# Do I have to keep or transfer my duplicate Pokemon to affect wild Pokemon's CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

I wonder how wild Pokemon CP is calculated and on what is based on? I listen it's based on the maximum CP you have (for this type of Pokemon?) but I'm not sure about that.

So my question is, do I have to keep all my duplicate Pokemon to have best results and remove lower when I'm full or do I have to keep only the best for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a MAX CP which is based on your trainer level. What you usually do is just transfer the lower ones of your pokemon group (same candy group). Even better is to evolve some of them then trade (evolve is +500Xp). I keep the best of each until the best ones get beaten by a higher level CP of the same pokemon (EG: pidgey (96 CP) vs Pidgey (168 CP), trade the 96CP pidgey).

Comment: @Arthur My brother gave me a bonus tip on the evolve part: Capture alot of the same pokemon (eg: ratatas) and then after your inventory is nearly full, just use a lucky egg, evolve and then transfer (1000xp instead of 500xp for half an hour). No problem #Valor :P

Comment: very good ! #Valor

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to keep any pokemon. The CP of a wild pokemon depends, as far as I know, only on your level.

I removed all my pidgeys and with every level up I sometimes see wild pidgeys with a better CP.

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood pokemon have 3 values that determine cp - attack, defense, and stamina. Part of this value is determined by the "species" so every pidgey has the same base stats. Part of this is determined by the individual values or "IVs" of the pokemon. IVs do not change during evolution. Finally, this value is scaled according to the level of the pokemon. The pokemon's max level is tied to your trainer level - but it will increase as you level up.

If your goal is to eventually have the strongest pokemon possible, you must figure out which of yours have the highest IVs and powerup and evolve those, as IVs determine the maximum potential of the pokemon.

The actual CP calculation, where base values are for the species, ind values are the IVs of the specific pokemon. 
(BaseAtk + IndAtk) * (BaseDef + IndDef)^0.5 * (BaseSta + IndSta)^0.5 * (ECpM)^2 / 10

ECpM is the CP modifier based on the pokemon level.

More information can be found here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4tzcmk/faq_on_ivs_info_megathread/
and here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongodev/comments/4t7xb4/exact_cp_formula_from_stats_and_cpm_and_an_update